# How to prove that if $p\mid n$, then $\Phi_{pn}(x)=\Phi_n(x^p)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

I'm trying to solve exercise 7.5.11 from Lovett's "*Abstract Algebra*":

> Suppose that $p\mid n$. Prove that $\Phi_{pn}(x)=\Phi_n(x^p)$.

Here, $\Phi_n(x)$ is the $n$th cyclotomic polynimial and I don't think $p$ is restricted to prime numbers. I fixed an integer $p\geq 1$ and tried to prove that $\Phi_{p^{k+1}}(x)=\Phi_{p^k}(x^p)$ for all integer $k\geq 1$. I tried using mathematical induction on $k$ but I couldn't prove that it holds when $k=1$.

Comment: How is $\Phi_n$ defined in your book? If it is via roots of unity, then you need to prove that a complex number $a$ is a primitive $pn$-th root of unity if and only if $a^p$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

Comment: I believe $p$ must be prime, I've managed to prove the case $k=1$ only with $p$ prime

Comment: @Theleb I also thought that the author could have missed out to write that $p$ is a prime number. But I checked that the case $k=1$ holds when $p\leq 7$. That's why I think that $p$ is an arbitrary positive integer.

Comment: @zxcv How did you prove the result for $p \leq 7$ ? [There] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) is another reason why I think $p$ must be prime. Have you checked it ?

Comment: @darij Okay I proved what you said. Then I deduced that if $p|n$, then $\Phi_{pn}(x)$ and $\Phi_n(x^p)$ have the same roots. So if I prove either that $\Phi_{n}(x^p)$ doesn't have double roots or that $\Phi_{n}(x^p)$ have the same degree as $\Phi_{pn}(x)$, then I'm done. But how do I prove one of those?

Comment: @Theleb Which part of the link should I see?

Comment: If a polynomial $f$ has no double roots, then neither has $f\left(x^m\right)$.

Comment: @Theleb: No, $p$ doesn't have to be prime. Actually, the prime case quickly yields the general case.

Comment: @darij I got it. Thanks!